# Count word class in python

Tags: python, list, function, class, loops

I want to create a class which has a function to count the words in a string which is passed through the function as a parameter (is my terminology correct?). This is what I have an it gives me an error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sentence'.

```
class myHacks:
    def __init__(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence

    def countWords(self):
        my_list = []
        my_list = self.sentence.split(" ")
        counter = 0
        for m in my_list:
            counter += 1
        return counter
```

myHacks.countWords("please count me")

Comment: You might also find this useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Just use `collections.Counter` like @JoshSmeaton said, unless you really want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: ```str.split``` returns a list.  The *built-in* function ```len``` will return the number of items in the list.  No need to (explicitly) iterate and accumulate with a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is just a function, not a class. Classes have to be instantiated, and are used when you need to do more than just one operation on a related set of data. For your single use case, a function will probably suffice:

```
def countWords(sentence):
    my_list = []
    counter = 0
    for s in sentence:
        counter += 1
    return(counter)
```

Also, you never use `my_list`, and you're counting letters in that sentence, not words. This is probably what you need instead:

```
def countWords(sentence):
    return len(sentence.split())
```

In order to use your method, with a class, like you've written, you'd have to call it this way:

```
hacks = myHacks('this is my sentence')
hacks.countWords()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the class instantiation with the method call, you should instantiate a class with the correct string

```
h = myHacks("please count me")
```

and then call the countWords method on the new object

```
h.countWords()
```